# How can I change icon size in Empathy in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, empathy

I upgraded from 12.04 to **13.04**, and after I realized that the **icon size** (or theme) of **contact list** of **Empathy** can not be changed. Is it true? Or could I not find the setting? The huge icons are very pesky for me because I have a lot of contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cant be changed without modifying the source code, or writing some sort of extension of your own. I find this just as frustrating, makes it more difficult to use at work.